# How to find which kernel version has a certain package?

Tags: linux, package-management, distributions

I am looking for a kernel that supports `linux-tools-generic` package with it's exact version for supporting `usbip`.Package sites do not let you search a package for a specific version and even if they did, it's hard to consider all linux distros and all their version. How to find the exact version of kernel that support a specific package ?

Comment: Could you explain what you’re trying to do in more detail? The kernel has had support for USB/IP since 2014, so any version you’ll find currently is technically capable of enabling it. Are you trying to find which kernel packages *enable* USB/IP?

Comment: Actually I am using a non-standard kernel that hasbeen customized and removed usbip.

Comment: Are you looking for a “standard” kernel package, or do you want something that works with your specific customised kernel?

Comment: What is your distribution, please?

Comment: I am using Debian 11.2 (Bullseye) and want to install a kernel that supports usbip and hence has the package ```linux-tools-generic ```

Comment: Thanks, I’ve updated my answer based on that information.

Answer (score 0):

Both the (Ubuntu) `linux-tools-generic` and `usbip` packages are built from the kernel. If you’re running your own kernel, you won’t be able to find compatible packages in the repositories; it’s up to you to build the tools yourself (in `tools/usb/usbip` in the kernel source).

If your kernel really doesn’t support USB/IP, there’s nothing that can be done other than switching to a kernel which does.

Based on your comment,

> I am using Debian 11.2 (Bullseye) and want to install a kernel that supports usbip and hence has the package `linux-tools-generic`

what you should do is install whatever kernel package is appropriate for your architecture, and the `usbip` package:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-$(dpkg --print-architecture) usbip
```

Debian doesn’t have a `linux-tools-generic` package, that’s a Ubuntu package; the relevant package for USB/IP support in Debian is [`usbip`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/usbip), and it matches the default kernel for whatever suite you’re using (so Debian 11 currently has version 2.0+5.10.92-1, matching kernel 5.10.92; Bullseye backports has version 2.0+5.15.15-2~bpo11, matching kernel 5.15.15).